# If $\tan\alpha=-3,$ then calculate $\cos\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan\alpha=-3,$ then $\cos\alpha$ is: A) $-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$; B) $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$; C) $\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$; D) $-\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$

We are given that $\tan\alpha=\dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha}=-3\Rightarrow \sin\alpha=-3\cos\alpha$. We can plug this into $$\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha=1\\\left(-3\cos\alpha\right)^2+\cos^2\alpha=1\\10\cos^2\alpha=1\\\cos^2\alpha=\dfrac{1}{10}\Rightarrow \cos\alpha=\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}=\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{10}}{10}$$ So both A) and B) are correct answers?!

Comment: Without further information on which quadrant the angle lies in, you do not know the sign of the cosine. So your understanding is correct.

Comment: Without further information, yes. Generally, if $\tan t= a/b$, then $\sin t =\pm a/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and $\cos t=b/\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ (where the signs are chosen the same).

Comment: We know that $\cos^2\alpha=1/(1+\tan^2\alpha)$ because by extracting the square root we will have a double sign that cannot be established if we do not know the quadrant where the angle is defined. After I am totally agree with @Lubin.

Comment: @Sebastiano Hi friendo

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Hi kind friend :-)

Comment: Note that what you wrote is different from saying that $\alpha=\tan^{-1} (-3)$ because in the latter case we have information about the quadrant of $\alpha$.